# PyCharm doesn't see module

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm does not see the turtle standard library - a turtle for learning python. (OS Linux Mint)

On another computer (Ubuntu/PyCharm) the code works without errors.
On the same run in Spyder and through the terminal: *python3 1.py - works.*
It is PyCharm, installed from the application manager, that is broken.

If you remove PyCharm installed from the application manager and install from the JetBrains website, then the code also works.

I also noticed that PyCharm with JetBrains works with python3.5 (as in the system), and PyCharm from the application manager with python3.9.

What tried:

- select a system interpreter: /usr/bin/python3 (for some reason, the 3.9 version also appears at the specified address)
- reinstall PyCharm from application manager
- reset File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings

**Nothing helps**

```
import turtle
 
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(50)
```

Please help me figure out what is the reason for such capricious behavior of PyCharm

`/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/max/PycharmProjects/tttttttt/1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/max/PycharmProjects/tttttttt/1.py", line 1, in <module>
import turtle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: Are you using the flatpack version of Pycharm ?

Comment: i dont know what is flatpack version. I installed it from manager of programms linux mint

Comment: Pycharm's flatpack installation is known to have many issues, such as this one. I really advise you to uninstall it and install from [Jetbrains site](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux) instead. You can also install [Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) instead, so you don't have any problems with updates.

Comment: Flatpack vinstallation is it, what i installed from program manager in linux mint? I don't like PyCharm from JetBrains-site, becouse it is not installation version. It is portable. How i can to install PyCharm in my system?

Comment: You downloaded a Flatpack version. What about using `snap` then ? I still recommend you to use the version available on the Jetbrains site, it's not a portable version.

Comment: ok, i understood. PyCharm from program manager linux mint - it is flatpack version. But snap what is it? Ok, i'll intall PyCharm from JetBrains

Answer (score 0):

do `pip list` or `pip freeze` and check all the installed packages and is turtle installed in current environment or not
I would suggest to use `venvs` for projects your are trying to work with

1. `python3 -m venv venv`
2. `source venv/bin/activate`
3. `pip3 install turtle`

Do this in your terminal. In case if you currently have some venv installed try to activate it with option 2. of the answer

Comment: I wrote `python3 -m venv venv` NEXT `source venv/bin/activate` NEXT `python 1.py` works in terminal, module found. I didn't even `pip3 install turtle`
But, when I opened PyCharm, opened the project, selected the `/venv/bin/python3` interpreter - it didn't work. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'

Comment: could you try `pip freeze` in pycharm terminal, when venv is activated?

Comment: Also you can try `ctrl+shift+s` in pycharm and choose Python Interpreter, there, it will give you the list of installed packages for current project's interpreter